# Exclude elasticsearchTemplate from Spring-Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have an application that use Elasticsearch and I'd like to disable this integration when I'm testing some controllers. How can I disable elasticsearchTemplate on Spring-Boot test?

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.closeupinternational.comclosure.elasticsearch")
public class Application {
...
```

Repository.class:

```
@Repository
public interface PipelineRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Pipeline, String> {
...
```

Test Controller.class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class,
ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
@WebMvcTest(ProductionCycleExecutionController.class)
@Slf4j
public class ProductionCycleExecutionControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductionCycleExecutionService prodCycleExecService;

    ...
```

I'm not using inside ProductionCycleExecutionService and I don't wanna try to test elasticsearch repository PipelineRepository at this moment.

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pipelineRepository' defined in 
com.closeupinternational.comclosure.elasticsearch.PipelineRepository defined in
 @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on Application: Cannot resolve reference to bean 
'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration.class, ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})`

These annotations aim to bootstrap the whole Spring context and configure it

`@WebMvcTest` should be enough in your case as it bootstraps web-related context only

**Upd**

If you have any dependencies in your `ProductionCycleExecutionController` (like `elasticsearchTemplate` you mentioned) then mock them like this if you don't need to define their behavior, as follows:

```
@MockBeans(value = {@MockBean(YourBean1.class), @MockBean(YourBean2.class), @MockBean(YourBean3.class)})
```

If you do need to define mocking behavior then mock as property in class:

```
@MockBean
private YourBean yourBean;
```

Comment: Same error: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'elasticsearchTemplate' available`

Comment: @AldoInáciodaSilva please see my updated answer

Comment: I don't have any dependency with elasticsearch when I'm testing this part of system. Do you think is because I have elasticsearch properties defined in /test/application.yml?

Comment: Try to add `elasticsearchTemplate` in `@MockBeans` as well

Comment: I added `PipelineRepository` as `@MockBean` but it's extrange because I will need to put this reference in all my tests class.